# I have json file when the json file is changed I need to show the changes in python Console

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have local json file, I am beginner stage at python and I need to develop a code for while running python code it continuously checks the json file and if any changes in Json file I need to show the changes in Python console.

Eg.,
{
"a":2,
"b":3
}
if I change "a":3

python output:

change detected at key a and value 3.

I am missing logic here. and Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hia, Seems like you've got a project going on. Depending on what values you want to change and how deep in the JSON they are could add more work to the task. Let me see what i can come up with...

```
import essentials #  pip install mknxgn_essentials (not gonna lie, i made this module. biased...)
import time
import os
recordedjson = essentials.EsFileObject("Tools/Json.json").json
recoredchanges = essentials.EsFileObject("Tools/Changes.json")
if recoredchanges.json == False: # Used to save changes, also makes sure to keep previous logs
    recoredchanges.setjson([])
onchange_record_new_json = True # makes the new json the one you want to compare after each change
while True:
    newjson = essentials.EsFileObject('Tools/Json.json').json
    if recordedjson != newjson:
        changes = 0
        keychanges = 0
        newkeys = 0
        removedkeys = 0
        valuechanges = 0
        print("File has been changed! - Collecting Changes")
        for obj in recordedjson:
            if obj not in newjson:
                print("Key Removed From New Json Key:", obj)
                keychanges += 1
                removedkeys += 1
                changes += 1
            else:
                if recordedjson[obj] != newjson[obj]:
                    print("Value Change!")
                    print("Previous- Key: ", obj)
                    print("@ Value:", recordedjson[obj])
                    print(" New- Value:", newjson[obj])
                    valuechanges += 1
                    changes += 1
        for obj in newjson:
            if obj not in recordedjson:
                if obj not in newjson:
                    print("New Key Introduced- Key:", obj)
                    keychanges += 1
                    removedkeys += 1
                    changes += 1
        changelog = "Change Count: " + str(changes)
        changelog += " Key Changes: " + str(keychanges)
        changelog += " New Keys: " + str(newkeys)
        changelog += " Removed Keys: " + str(removedkeys)
        changelog += " Value Changes: " + str(valuechanges)
        print(changelog)
        record = {"Change Time": essentials.EsTimeObject().string}
        record["User Readable Time Change"] = essentials.EsTimeObject().readable
        record["Change Log"] = changelog
        recoredchanges.json.append(record)
        recoredchanges.save()
        time.sleep(10)
        if onchange_record_new_json:
            recordedjson = newjson
    print("Waiting For Change")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("cls") # cls for windows, clear for linux and so on...
```

man is it annoying to post code on this site..